# Nokia lumia 630 hangs when call initiated

Tags: calls, nokia-lumia-630

When call initiated the phone hangs; it gets stuck. To end the call, it has to be turned off, and when turned on, there is no call issues for 3 or 4 times. If any one calls me it comes as not reachable. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried a backup and factory reset of the phone?

Comment: Ya i have done it.. but the problem exists... If someone is calling me its coming as not reachable

Comment: Is your handset one from your network operator, or is it a generic version for your country?

Comment: Couldnt understand... I bought nokia lumia 630 dual sim from Nokia shop in India

Comment: One week before OS updated to lumia Denim.. whether this causes any issues..

Comment: Did you do a hard reset after the upgrade to Denim?

Comment: @RowlandShaw As vaishnavi mentioned it was brought in India it is clearly not sold by Network operator. As all Lumia phones(infact all GSM phones) in India are sold by phone manufactures only. NO phone is distributed by network operator.

Comment: @KolappanNathan Why is it clear that it's not an operator handset by being sold in India, to someone that is not familiar with the market there? This is why I'd sked for it to be clarified.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I added the comment for clarification only. What I meant to say is Network operators are not allowed to sell phones unless they themselves are manufactures. The word clearly in my comment was supposed to stress my point and not to say that it is clear for everyone. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You can try this Microsoft [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia/lumia-630-dual-sim-call-issues-after-denim-update/4ee35693-b5b5-490c-a3ba-d9c9fe45d258?auth=1) on call-related problems for this phone.